# ¿Como restringir algunas paginas a determinado usuario asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un login, uso form authentication. El login tiene un checkbox para verificar si el que se loguea es profesor. Si se si tilda el checkbox es profesor, si no es alumno.

Mi consulta es que en caso que si se loguea un profesor, no pueda entrar a ninguna vista de alumnos.En caso que sea alumno, no pueda entrar a ninguna vista de los profesores.

Desde el contralador Home tengo la accion ingresar que va a la vista de login.

```
public ActionResult Ingresar(String returnUrl)
{
     ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ingresar(string email,string password, string returnUrl , bool soyProfesor = false)
{
    bool login = UsuarioServicio.ingresar(email, password, soyProfesor);

        if (login)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                return Redirect(returnUrl);

            if (soyProfesor)
                return RedirectToAction("AdministrarPreguntas","Profesor");

            return RedirectToAction("VerRepuesta","Alumnos");
        }

        ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
        ViewBag.MensajeError = true;
        return View();
}
```

Despues tengo la clase UsuarioServicio donde busca en la base de datos:

```
public class UsuarioServicio
{
    public static bool ingresar(string email,string pass, bool soyProf)
    {
        TP_20191CEntities ctx = new TP_20191CEntities();

        if (soyProf)
        {
            Profesor prof = ctx.Profesor.Where(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == pass) as Profesor;

            if (prof != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"] = String.Format("{0} {1}", prof.Nombre,prof.Apellido);
                return true;
            }

        }
        else{
            Alumno al = ctx.Alumnos.Where(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == pass) as Alumno;

            if (al != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["Usuario"] = String.Format("{0} {1}", al.Nombre, al.Apellido);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

La vista es la siguiente:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Ingresar";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AnonimoLayout.cshtml";
 }

 <div id="fondo-login" class="bg-secondary">
   <div class="container" id="lg">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 shadow mx-auto pt-2 bg-primary">
            <h2 class="text-center text-white">Ingresar</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Ingresar", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "col-sm-6 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white mx-auto rounded-bottom", @id = "form-login" }))
        {
            if (ViewBag.MensajeError == true)
            {
                <div id="errorGeneral" name="errorGeneral" class="bg-danger">
                    <p class="text-white"> Email y/o contraseña invialdas.</p>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingresar email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Ingresar contraseña">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="soyProfesor" value="true" name="soyProfesor" >
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="soyProfesor">Soy profesor</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo la lógica de tu `login`. ¿Acaso el usuario decide si es profesor o alumno? Eso no es una buena práctica. Tu aplicación debe encargarse de diferenciar si el usuario es profesor o es alumno. Además, deberías postear el código de lo que estás intentando. Te invito a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Hola, actualice agregando codigo. De todas maneras mi consulta es, en caso que este logueado como profesor quiero que no pueda accedar a ninguna vista de alumnos. En caso que este logueado como alumno no pueda entrar a ninguna vista de profesores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo mucho que utilices roles de usuario para poder identificar ese tipo de acceso, pues pese a que tendrías que hacer un poco de trabajo extra haciendo la tabla de roles, eventualmente será mas sencillo controlar los accesos de usuarios basado en que rol o roles tiene cada uno. 
Voy a asumir que ya hiciste algo de investigación en cuanto al atributo [Authorize] y el uso de roles (Si no lo haz hecho te recomiendo que lo leas acá [Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) . Si tienes dudas con mucho gusto te puedo orientar.

Ahora, suponiendo que ya conoces esta solución pero por alguna razón no puedes hacer una tabla de roles, puedes hacer lo siguiente:
Crea un atributo [Authorize] a la medida que te permita recibir los parámetros del rol, si es "Profesor" o es "Alumno". Empezamos creando la siguiente clase:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    TP_20191CEntities ctx = new TP_20191CEntities(); //Estamos declarando el acceso a tu contexto de base de datos
    private readonly string[] usuariosPermitidos;
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        this.usuariosPermitidos = roles;
    }


    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        bool authorize = false;
        foreach (var usuario in usuariosPermitidos)
        {
            if (usuario == "Profesor") 
            {
                Profesor prof = ctx.Profesor.Where(x => x.Email == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) as Profesor;

                if (prof != null)
                {
                    authorize = true;
                }

            }
            else if (usuario == "Alumno")
            {
                Alumno al = ctx.Alumnos.Where(x => x.Email == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) as Alumno;

                if (al != null)
                {
                    authorize = true;
                }
            }

        }
        return authorize;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

Ahora en tus controladores podrás utilizar el atributo [Authorize] de la siguiente manera:

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ProfesorController : Controller
    {
        [CustomAuthorize("Profesor")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Bienvenido!";

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Logon");
            }

            return View();
        }
}


namespace MyProject.Web.Controllers
{
    public class AlumnoController : Controller
    {
        [CustomAuthorize("Alumno")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Bienvenido!";

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Logon");
            }

            return View();
        }
}
```

Ahora, también debo advertirte que no me parece muy buena práctica, lo deseable sería que utilices una tabla de roles, ¿porqué?, pues debido a que si tus roles crecen digamos que mas adelante además de "Profesor" tengas "Adminsitrativo", "Asesor" o "Sinodal" (Por dar algunos ejemplos), te vas a ver obligado a estar haciendo muchos "if" en la clase CustomAuthorizeAttribute.

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la repuesta. Me sirvio, lo hago  de esta manera porque dos dieron la base de datos y lo tenemos que usar sin tabla de roles.